# NextJS: Images loaded from cache don't trigger the onLoad event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently in the process of converting a ReactJS client side rendered application to a NextJS application for search engine optimization and social media linking reasons.

One of the components converted, which is basically an image that waits until it's finished loading then fades in, is not working as expected after it is used in a NextJS environment.

It behaves in the following manner:

Cache Enabled:

- The first time the image loads and the onLoad event triggers thus showing the image.
- The second time the image stays hidden because the onLoad event doesn't trigger when the image is loaded from cache.

Cache Disabled using devtools:

- The onLoad event always works because the image is never served from cache.

Expected behavior and the behavior previously achieved with using just ReactJS:

- The onLoad event should trigger whether the image was loaded from the cache or not.

When not using React this problem is usually caused when someone sets the images `src` before defining a `onload` function:

```
let img = new Image()
img.src = "img.jpg"
img.onload = () => console.log("Image loaded.")
```

Which should be:

```
let img = new Image()
img.onload = () => console.log("Image loaded.")
img.src = "img.jpg"
```

Here is simplified code that causes the same problem in NextJS:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Home = () => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

    const homeStyles = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "96vh",
        backgroundColor: "black"
    }

    const imgStyles = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        objectFit: "cover",
        opacity: loaded ? 1 : 0
    }

    const handleLoad = () => {
        console.log("Loaded")
        setLoaded(true)
    }

    return (
        <div className="Home" style={homeStyles}>
            <img alt=""
                onLoad={handleLoad}
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981001-5864b3250a69?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
                style={imgStyles}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Anyone have any idea that could send me in the right direction?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ended up using `ImageObject.complete` as a workaround thanks to someone's suggestion.

I used `useRef` to reference the image and checked if the `image.current.complete === true` on component mount.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

const Home = () => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

    const image = useRef()

    const homeStyles = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "96vh",
        backgroundColor: "black"
    }

    const imgStyles = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        objectFit: "cover",
        opacity: loaded ? 1 : 0
    }

    const handleLoad = () => setLoaded(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (image.current.complete) setLoaded(true)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="Home" style={homeStyles}>
            <img alt=""
                ref={image}
                onLoad={handleLoad}
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981001-5864b3250a69?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
                style={imgStyles}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: I know it's against the rules to make a comment that is just gratitude and nothing else, but thank you so much.  You are seriously a life saver.  <3

Answer (score 4):

From Next.js [v11.0.2-canary.4](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v11.0.2-canary.4) onwards, one can directly use [`onLoadingComplete`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#onloadingcomplete) prop.

```js
<Image src={src} onLoadingComplete={() => setLoaded(true)} />
```

---

How does this compare with other options??

- You get to keep using the awesome `next/image` component instead of unoptimized `img` tag without any extra code or dealing with refs yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new `Image` component from nextjs 10, which does not support a forward ref, you can modify the workaround with

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
useEffect(() => {
  if ((ref.current?.firstChild?.firstChild as HTMLImageElement | undefined)?.complete) {
    setLoaded(true)
  }
}, [])

return <div ref={ref}>
         <Image src={src} 
           onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}/>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I only want to add to @mohamed-seif-khalid answer that I had to add a check in useEffect if ref consist anything, because my render continued to break.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (image.current && image.current.complete) {
      handleImageLoad()
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: The same can be done for videos with `const isLoaded = videoRef.current.readyState === 4;`