# How to present a blurred version of an image in NextJS as it's being downloaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, blur

I'm looking for a similar effect as this one below:

> [image: blur image effect]

I have done something similar with Gatsby, but I'm wondering if this is possible to do with NextJS?

Comment: you have to create 2 versions of images, load both the images simultaneously via img tag, and when original images loaded hide blur image. 
you can manage hide via state `<img src="original.png" onLoad={() => thi.setState({ loaded: true })} />   `

Comment: NextJS 11 provides such a feature : https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it without using an external library with not much code.

https://codepen.io/darajava/pen/GRZzpbB?editors=0110

I added animations in there too on load. The image will fit to the width of its parent container. Usage is simple:

```html
<LoadImage largeImageSrc={url} smallImageSrc={url} />
```

Answer (score 12):

For version above 10.2 Nextjs is providing built in blur image in Image component.
After spending hours I found this [article](https://abstack.pk/post/how-to-add-a-placeholder-image-in-nextjs)

First you need to update your nextJs app to 10.2.4 or above version.

```
yarn add next@10.2.4
```

Then implement your nextJs Image component with two addtional props **blurDataURL** and **placeholder**. Check the code example below.

```
<Image
   className="image-container"
   src="/images/high-quality-image.jpg"
   width={250}
   height={240}
   quality={75}
   blurDataURL="/images/path-to-blur-image.jpg"
   placeholder="blur"
/>
```

Next.js Update:

Next.js now support placeholder="blur" you can use it in the image component:

```
<Image src={author} alt="Picture of the author" placeholder="blur" />
```

Answer (score 5):

With Next.js v11, this is supported internally:

```js
import Image from 'next/image';
import someImg from 'path/to/some/image.png';

// ...

<Image src={someImg} placeholder="blur" />
```

References:

- https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#image-placeholders
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#placeholder

Also, [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18858) discussed a whole lot of alternatives, which can be helpful if you are using lower versions or trying to use this with non-static images.

---

Official demo: https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/placeholder

[The example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/placeholder.js) can be animated if you want: ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68420896/11613622))

```js
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useState } from 'react';

import ViewSource from '../components/view-source';
import mountains from '../public/mountains.jpg';

const PlaceholderBlur = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <ViewSource pathname="pages/placeholder.js" />
      <h1>Image Component With Placeholder Blur</h1>
      <Image
        alt="Mountains"
        src={mountains}
        placeholder="blur"
        width={700}
        height={475}
        className={loaded ? 'unblur' : ''}
        onLoadingComplete={() => setLoaded(true)}
      />
      <style jsx global>{`
        .unblur {
          animation: unblur 1s linear;
        }

        @keyframes unblur {
          from {
            filter: blur(20px);
          }
          to {
            filter: blur(0);
          }
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

export default PlaceholderBlur;
```

Result:

[image]

---

How does this compare with other options??

- You get to keep using the awesome `next/image` instead of unoptimized `img` tag or not-so-optimized third-party implementations.
- No need to add additional dependencies, i.e. bundle size won't be effected much.
- No need to manually generate a tiny image to show as preview. Next.js automatically generates a very small (<10px) image for you.

Comment: I do not think the preview will be smaller than 10 pixels.

Comment: @france1 That blurred version has size less than 10px. Refer https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#blurdataurl Here is the implementation if you want to read: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/558632b5f2bb9c78e4a234813a07c45ccaacbf0c/packages/next/src/build/webpack/loaders/next-image-loader/blur.ts#L4 (generated image height/width is less than or equal to 8px here)

Answer (score -1):

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

import sanity from '../../utils/sanity';

export function urlFor(source) {
  return imageUrlBuilder(sanity).image(source);
}

const SanityImage = ({ src, width, height, alt, ...props }) => (
  <Image
    src={urlFor(src).width(width).height(height).url()}
    width={width}
    height={height}
    layout="responsive"
    placeholder="blur"
    alt={alt || 'kickoff'}
    blurDataURL="/images/coverImage.png"
    {...props}
  />
);

export default SanityImage;
```